# Google App Script Syntax cannot retrieve editor syntax

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Recently, I have a google spreadsheet that is installed with appscript. The script was used to limit edit only to several email. And this is the full script:

```
function LimitPakYoga(e) {
  var allowedEmails = ["suryaprayoga.business@gmail.com", "antonioryan2101@gmail.com"];
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var editorEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  console.log("Event Object: " + JSON.stringify(e)); // Log the entire event object
  console.log("Editor's Email: " + editorEmail);
  console.log("Allowed Emails: " + allowedEmails);

  if (sheet.getName() === "Daily_S3") {
    if (allowedEmails.indexOf(editorEmail) === -1) {
      range.setValue(e.oldValue);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You are not allowed to edit this column.");
    }
  }
}
```

However, the script  var editorEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); returns nothing in the log. Can anyone help me in solving this problem? I really need this script to work accordingly to secure my data. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Ryan Antonio, I want to ask for further details. Do you want to get the current user that editing your spreadsheet or the current user who accessing your spreadsheet? Thank you!

Comment: If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string.[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser)

Comment: I want to get the current user who is editing the spreadsheet